# Is there any way to map more than one Entity to a physical Table in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I am using EF4.1.

I have a large generic physical table, in SQL Server 2008 SP2, as such:

```
Class Table:
  Id
  S1
  S2
  I1
  I2
```

I would like to map multiple EF entities for different "domain" purposes to this one physical table, ie:

```
Car Entity
  Id -> Id (Class)
  Name -> S1 (Class)
  Cost -> I1 (Class)

Dog Entity
  Id -> Id (Class)
  Name -> S1 (Class)
  Age  -> I1 (Class)
```

This is a contrived example to show my point. It seems that EF does not allow me to map "Car" and "Dog" to the "Class" table, because of potential "PK Collisions". The best solution I have arrived at, to date, is to use Database Views to implement "Car" and "Dog". I need to read and write to these entities as well.

I do realise that many will recommend that I should just set up a "Dog" and "Car" table. However this is a specific reason for the approach above.

So my main question is, am I correct in thinking that mapping multiple entities to one physical entity is not possible.

Finally, what approach would you recommend?

Thank in in advance.

Comment: You should have entity type discriminator column if you want to map several types to single table

Comment: Hi, thanks for for this. So are you saying that by not defining the discriminator column, then that is causing my "PK collision" error in my EF designer. I actually use Devart's Entity Developer.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen Devart's Entity Develper

Comment: I think Entity Developer is a slight side issue. I think my question is more about Entity Framework, and whether one should be able to setup multiple Entities that reuse the same underlying table, and also to reuse the columns for different purposes. For example  "S1" could be "Name" for "Type1" and "ReferenceCode" for "Type2". At the moment it seems that one cannot mix them up so if "Name" is mapped to "S1" then "ReferenceCode" cannot be then mapped to "S1", but some other column like "S2". Is this correct? If so I have a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: At the moment I keep getting this error message: "1 Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 1038:EntitySets 'Car' and 'Dog' are both mapped to table 'Class'. Their primary keys may collide."

Comment: Having researched this further, I believe this is impossible. One has to use Database Views, unless someone can disagree and put a smile on my face !!!

Comment: This strongly smells like something you shouldn't do at all. It violates core principles of relational databases.

Comment: I guess you could do it anyway by using a base class with only the id, derived from this the car and dog classes and TPH. You would however have to supply a discriminator column and map to it.

Comment: Gert, Thanks for your reply. My key issue is that I have multiple concepts. I would rather not create a table for each one. I am attempting to create a generic mechanism for these concepts. So I suppose I am trying to create a table called "organism" rather than one for "cat", one for "dog" and one for "Fish". Obviously attributes for "fish" are different for "Dog", some will be used, some will not. In the Entity layer I was planning to create "dog", "cat" and "Fish" entities. Perhaps it could be argued that one should stay with the "organism" entity throughout as a higher level concept?

Comment: Stephen, Thanks for this. I have tried TPH, but I can only use 1 base class property for 1 derived class property. So I could not use "S1" for "Model" for type= "Car" and "S1" for "Breed" for type="Dog". Once "S1" has been allocated to the "Car" entity, that is that. This means that the physical table will become very sparse. This is my understanding. Is it correct?

Comment: AFAIK you could map the properties "model" and "breed" both to the "S1" column. In Fluent API e.g.: `modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Property(c=>c.Model).HasColumnName("S1")` and `modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().Property(d=>d.Breed).HasColumnName("S1")`.  I have absolutely no idea if this will work, though.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Interesting point. I am not using Fluent API, but rather a designer, namely Devart Entity Developer. It certainly does not allow reuse. Perhaps this is correct, semantically,  since each column is just used for one purpose. However it does mean there would be many columns in the table ie 50, many would be null. I feel this is bad, but this could just be an unnecessary hangup of mine. If this was fine, and SQL Server can certainly deal with nulls efficiently via SPARSE, then TPH seems very plausible and useful, and I should just get on and use TPH, and stop worrying.

Comment: I did indeed resolve this. Devart told me how to do it in their Enditity Developer product which I use. I am also using TPH. Thanks all. Not sure who I award an answer to since a number of folks have helped.